# Grouping the ip addresses returns 15 instead of 3

Tags: sql, group-by

I want to group the ip addresses so it returns 3 instead of 15 as it does with the SQL code below.

Here's how it looks like in my database:

```
ID    IDP   IDU  DATE                   INFO_IP
 1    19    0    2012-11-14 00:42:03    127.0.0.1
 2    19    0    2012-11-14 00:42:40    127.0.0.1
 3    19    0    2012-11-14 00:45:01    127.0.0.1
 4    19    0    2012-11-14 00:47:24    127.0.0.1
 5    19    0    2012-11-14 00:48:35    127.0.0.1
 6    19    0    2012-11-14 00:48:57    127.0.0.1
 7    19    0    2012-11-14 00:53:41    127.0.0.1
 8    19    0    2012-11-14 01:02:12    127.0.0.1
 9    19    0    2012-11-14 01:02:55    127.0.0.1
10    19    0    2012-11-14 01:03:03    127.0.0.1
11    19    0    2012-11-14 01:03:20    127.0.0.2
12    19    0    2012-11-14 01:03:28    127.0.0.2
13    19    0    2012-11-14 01:04:16    127.0.0.2
14    19    0    2012-11-14 01:04:33    127.0.0.3
15    19    0    2012-11-14 01:04:40    127.0.0.3
```

And here is the SQL code:

```
SELECT idp, COUNT(info_ip) FROM photos_watched
WHERE idp = '19'
GROUP BY info_ip
LIMIT 1
```

What have I missed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `DISTICT` for INFO-IP??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to count the distinct IP :

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT INFO_IP)
FROM photos_watched
WHERE idp = 19;
```

Your current query counts the number of IP in each group.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be

```
SELECT info_ip, COUNT(*) 
FROM photos_watched
WHERE idp = '19'
GROUP BY info_ip
```